# Stream Unity RenderTexture to Gstreamer

Tags: unity-game-engine, gstreamer

I would like to export a Camera view to a native plugin implementing a GStreamer pipeline which encodes and streams the rendered texture over a network to a web browser. I did some research and figured out that the best way to do that is probably to use a [RenderTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html) in Unity.

However, I don't understand how to interface this RenderTexture with GStreamer inside a native plugin. Do I need to write my own GStreamer source element for this? If yes, what would be a good starting point? Or is there another more straightforward solution for exporting the Camera view from Unity into GStreamer?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possible way how to do this using `openGL` and `appsrc`.
For even more details refer to [Unity low-level native plug-in interface documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html) and the corresponding [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NativeRenderingPlugin) available on GitHub. There is also a nice [tutorial](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/short-cutting-the-pipeline.html?gi-language=c) on how to use `appsrc`.

Here is a short summary what needs to be done:

### Unity (c#)

On Unity part you have to get your camera, create a `RenderTexture` and assign it to the camera. Then you have to give the `GetNativeTexturePtr` of that texture to your native plugin. Here are the most relevant parts of the code how this can be done:

```cs
...
[DllImport("YourPluginName")] 
private static extern IntPtr GetRenderEventFunc();
[DllImport("YourPluginName")] 
private static extern void SetTextureFromUnity(System.IntPtr texture, int w, int h);
...

IEnumerator Start()
{
  CreateTextureAndPassToPlugin();
  yield return StartCoroutine("CallPluginAtEndOfFrames");
}

private void CreateTextureAndPassToPlugin()
{
  // get main camera and set its size
  m_MainCamera = Camera.main;
  m_MainCamera.pixelRect = new Rect(0, 0, 512, 512);

  // create RenderTexture and assign it to the main camera
  m_RenderTexture = new RenderTexture(m_MainCamera.pixelWidth, m_MainCamera.pixelHeight, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
  m_RenderTexture.Create();
  m_MainCamera.targetTexture = m_RenderTexture;
  m_MainCamera.Render();

  // Pass texture pointer to the plugin
  SetTextureFromUnity(m_RenderTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr(), m_RenderTexture.width, m_RenderTexture.height);
}

private IEnumerator CallPluginAtEndOfFrames()
{
  while(true) 
  {
    // Wait until all frame rendering is done
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    // Issue a plugin event with arbitrary integer identifier.
    GL.IssuePluginEvent(GetRenderEventFunc(), m_EventID);
  }
}
```

### Native plugin (c++)

Here you have to store your texture handle and then access the pixel data on the rendering thread for example like this:

```cpp
extern "C" void UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API SetTextureFromUnity(void* textureHandle, int w, int h)
{
  g_TextureHandle = textureHandle;
  g_TextureWidth = w;
  g_TextureHeight = h;
}

static void OnRenderEvent(int eventID)
{

  uint32_t uiSize = g_TextureWidth * g_TextureHeight * 4; // RGBA = 4
  unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char[uiSize]; 

  GLuint gltex = (GLuint)(size_t)(g_TextureHandle);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gltex);
  glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pData);

  // now we have our pixel data in memory, we can now feed appsrc with it
  ...
}

extern "C" UnityRenderingEvent UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API GetRenderEventFunc()
{
  return OnRenderEvent;
}
```

As soon as you get the pixel data you can wrap it into `GstBuffer` and feed your pipeline using `push-buffer` signal:

```cpp
GstBuffer* pTextureBuffer = gst_buffer_new_wrapped(pData, uiSize);
...
g_signal_emit_by_name(pAppsrc, "push-buffer", pTextureBuffer, ...);
```

In case someone knows how to feed the pipeline with the openGL texture handle directly (without copying it into RAM) I would appreciate some input on this.